# About Credit Card Referral epidemics

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score

I have recently come into an epidemic of credit card referrals. My friends are going berserk in referring to each other and having bits and pieces of commotions about 'fair shares'. In one incident, there was also a negotiation about how much money will be split if a referral bonus is received. Multiple banks and credit card companies have sprouted in their discussions, Amex, Capital One, Chase are to name a bunch.

I have always been a less materialist person to my utter nature. At this stage of their mini-economic frenzy, I am too afraid to ask the questions to my friends to be humiliated to be in the game so late. So I come here to ask to the arena of altruists:

1. Are such referrals good for credit scores?
2. How many cards one can have not to harm your credit profile?
3. Do all banks and commerce orgs provide such scheme, if so how one knows about these?

Comment: your friends are splitting referral rewards with eachother?  Like I refer you, you sign up, Chase pays me a referral of $50, and I'm supposed to share that?

Comment: Yes, the amount is around 200$ I believe and there were negotiations about it to split 50-50 or so.

Comment: Referrals are a common marketing scheme.  I recommend a **MAX** of four CC accounts, and **preferably** just *two** (one to use, and one as a backup in case the other is lost, stolen, compromised).

Comment: @RonJohn I don't seem to be harmed by having more.  I have one primary, one backup for it, my oldest card and some other specialty ones that pay higher rewards in certain situations.  Our credit rating hovers around 800 with no installment debt left in our credit histories.

Comment: @RonJohn  I have two CCs from two different companies. I applied for one more from a referral request. Where do you check your credit score from? Credit Karma?

Comment: Chase, CapitalOne and BoA web sites offer it as a free service if you've got some sort of account with them.

Comment: Don't the terms and conditions usually disallow the splitting of referral bonuses?

Comment: @RonJohn: Why?  Given that a few years ago, companies were paying you several hundred bucks to sign up for cards?  I have several that I haven't used since the initial "spend $X in the first 3 months and we'll give you $Y" period expired.

Comment: @jamesqf why should the fact that "they" are offering you money to open CC accounts be the arbiter of whether it's financially wise to open CC accounts?

Comment: @RonJohn: It's a factor.  I mean, it's free money, right?  What's the downside?  Assuming of course that you are financially disciplined, and don't go running up charges for stuff you wouldn't otherwise have bought, and get stuck paying interest.  (My credit rating likewise is around 800, with no debt other than a nearly paid off mortgage.)

Comment: @jamesqf OP asks about credit score and credit profile.  Having lots of cards makes it harder to get a low rate mortgage, since you have the *capacity* to run up a lot of expensive debt.  I wouldn't be surprised if it also affects car loan rates.

Comment: @RonJohn: Didn't seem to affect my fairly recent refinance.  The lack of W2 income was a far bigger problem :-(  And car loans?  Not something I'm even going to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a referral has any effect on your credit score.  It's the person opening the card whose credit score is affected. I also don't think that the number of cards open affects it much.  It's how you manage your credit that's most important.

Credit card companies are always offering bonuses.  A good one is $200 for spending $500 within 3 months.  Google "Best credit card bonuses".  There are lots of web sites that update regularly as each new deal becomes available.  The bonus is not taxable.

Banks also offer bonuses for opening checking and/or money market accounts.  These bonuses are not as profitable as the credit card bonuses but it's occasionally possible to get an annualized yield in the low teens.  The bank bonus is taxable.

Not that I'd be willing to share my bonuses but if I were to speculate on what's fair for profit sharing, I'd say that the provider of the referral and the person opening the card should split it.  Anything else becomes too complicated and likely contentious.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for letting me know that 'bank bonuses are taxed'. I think I will be happy with 3 CCs so far and if anyone asks for a referral would be happy to do that. Otherwise, let it be.